# Proving that $|\sin(z)|^2 = \sin(x)^2+\sinh(y)^2$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, hyperbolic-functions

**Goal:** Prove $|\sin(z)|^2 = \sin(x)^2+\sinh(y)^2$

---

I have
\begin{align*}
\sin(x+iy)
&=\sin(x)\cos(iy)+\cos(x)\sin(iy)\\
&=\sin(x)\cosh(y)+i\cos(x)\sinh(y)\\
|\sin(z)|^2
&=\sin(x)^2 \cosh(x)^2+\cos(x)^2\sinh(y)^2
\end{align*}

How do I proceed?

Comment: did you mean $\cosh(\color{red}y)$?

Comment: Are we meant to have $z = x + iy$? I assume so, but no harm in being clear.

Comment: your second line is wrong as it is $\sin(x)\cosh(y)+i\cos(x)\sinh(y)$ and then you get $|\sin(z)|^2=\sin(x)^2 \cosh(y)^2+\cos(x)^2\sinh(y)^2$, so using $\cosh^2 (y)=\sinh^2(y)+1$ you are good

Comment: Note that you now corrected $x$ to $y$ in the second line, but not in the third line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to proceed:**

Replace $\cos^2$ with $1-\sin^2$ and $\cosh^2$ with $1+\sinh^2$

(Also note that $\cos(iy)=\cosh(\color{red}y)$.)